# Rename certain files with part of parent directory name

Tags: bash, files, directory, rename

I would like to identify files that meet certain string criteria in subdirectories, then rename those files with the final portion of the directory name, 2 directories up ("pd1"?), then I would like to move all of the renamed files to a separate directory.

More detail: say I run the hypothetical code from `/x/y/z` directory and in that directory are directories with names like '`20150416_110508_3006`'. The files I'm looking to rename are in (example) '`/x/y/z/20150416_110508_3006/dicom`', example file name '`o20150416_110508MPRAGESAGs002a1001.nii`'. The important elements of the filename needed to differentiate it from like files are the prefix "`o`", the '`s002a`' in the middle and the extension "`.nii`".

I wanted to rename these files with the final portion of the pd1 directory, in this case '`3006`', so '`3006.nii`'. Then after doing this for all applicable files, I would like to move the renamed files to a directory in '`/x/y/z`'.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '/x/y/z/*_*_(*)/dicom/o*s002a*.nii' '${f:h}/$1.nii'
```

Or:

```
zmv -n '/x/y/z/*_*_(*)/dicom/o*s002a*.nii' '/x/y/z/somedir/$1.nii'
```

To move them to `somedir` in `/x/y/z`.

Remove the `-n` to actually do the rename after you're satisfied it does what you want.

`zmv` would detect conflicting renames prior to starting any of the renames. Doing something similar with other shells like `bash` would require a longer script. Something like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
typeset -A seen
shopt -s nullglob
for file in /x/y/z/*_*_*/dicom/o*s002a*.nii; do
  tag=${file%/*/*}
  tag=${tag##*_}
  if [[ ${seen[$tag]} ]]; then
    printf >&2 '"%s" and "%s" both map to "%s"\n' "$file" "${seen[$tag]}" "$tag"
    exit 1
  fi
  seen[$tag]=$file
done
for tag in "${!seen[@]}"; do
  echo mv -i -- "${seen[$tag]}" "/x/y/z/somedir/$tag"
done
```

(untested)

(remove the `echo` to perform the rename).

Note that `bash` associative arrays (contrary to ksh93 or zsh) have a bug/limitation in that you can't have elements with an empty key. So if you have some `foo_bar_/dicom/*.nii` files, that won't work properly, so even for that programmatic approach I would still go with `zsh` or `ksh93` instead of `bash`.

Comment: I am using bash in redhat, I tried the command 'autoload zmv' but bash returns 'bash: autoload: command not found'.

Comment: @focusbob, hence the _With `zsh`_, and not _With `bash`_. `zsh` is available on RedHat systems as well even if not always installed by default.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the ability to install new tools, unfortunately.

Comment: @focusbob, see edit for a bash4 solution. Note that as long as there's a directory you have write access to and has no execution prevention in place (like /var/tmp or your home directory), you should be able to install zsh there. It's only to install software system-wide that you need superuser privileges.

Comment: When I run the bash script, I get: './rename.sh: line 2: typeset: -A: invalid option
typeset: usage: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value] ...' It otherwise appears to work however with 2 remaining issues: 1) I need the renamed files to retain the .nii extension, 2) I learned some folders have additional unnecessary information following an additional underscore. For example, 20150402_143041_3008_V1, and I just want to name the file 3008.nii. Would you please suggest modifications?

Comment: I've found workarounds for "1)" and "2)" requests in my above comment that are not elegant but work. I still can't fix the error (can anyone help?): `typeset: -A: invalid option typeset: usage: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value]`